# Array_sum seems to be not working properly Php

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, asynchronous

I'm playing with league of legends $api and async requests , but right now i have a problem , i can't
sum all kills from  participant id == 1

array_sum  is only showing the kills from each game and not  the sum of the all (screenshot)
the expected result is to be 122 (sum of all kills from the participant Id 1)

this is my code:

```
<?php



// Function to be called on request success
 $onSuccess = function (Objects\MatchDto  $match) {

  foreach ($match->participants as $team) {
       
        if ($team->participantId==1 and $team->teamId==100) {
            
              $t[]=$team->stats->kills.'</br>';
              var_dump (array_sum($t)); echo '</br>';

        }    
    } 


};
// Function to be called on request failure
$onFailure = function ($ex) {
    echo "Error occured: {$ex->getMessage()}";
};

 //I have a bunch of match_ids from league of legends games saved in my db
 // so,  foreach $custom is to get all match_ids
 // $api variable is an array with all initializtion settings
 // $match is basically getting me the match with that matchid from my db ex: getMatch('1234567')

    foreach ($custom as $games) {
    
    $api->nextAsync($onSuccess, $onFailure);

    $match=$api->getMatch($games->match_id);
    
}



$api->commitAsync();



?>
```

[image]

this is what array_sum is returning to me , instead of expected result 122.

Comment: Why is that expected? You sum and dump every time you iterate through (that's a hint, move it outside the foreach)

Comment: i expect 122 as a result  because  is the sum of all  those numbers , and even outside the foreach is showing each number and not the sum

Comment: You're not initialising `$t` before you start pushing values onto it. You're then concatenating a string to every value before adding it to the array, ensuring that you have an array of strings to add up. Under PHP's rules this might actually work, but I wouldn't rely on it.

Comment: You must initialize $t above/outside foreach and array_sum below foreach and remove the string `<br>'

Comment: but i can only initialize the $t  inside that foreach;

Comment: And why is that? What's the compulsion

Comment: `array_sum` works just fine. for simplicity sake, you don't even need it. a simple `$t = 0;` and `$t += kills` summation should suffice.

Comment: @Kevin very good point, I'm updating the answer to reflect that better alternative.

Comment: im getting the exactly same result as before , i dont know why
but what i've notice is , it seems the foreach with $custom is passing through  the $onsucess function , if i erase everything on  the $onsuccess function , and echo just "test" , it prints out  33 "test" , the exact same number of matchesid that i have on my db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

    $onSuccess = function(Objects\MatchDto  $match, &$t){
        foreach ($match->participants as $team){
            if ($team->participantId==1 and $team->teamId==100){
                  $t+=$team->stats->kills;
            }    
        }
    };

    $onFailure = function($ex){
        echo "Error occurred: {$ex->getMessage()}";
    };
    $t = 0;
    foreach($custom as $games){
        $api->nextAsync($onSuccess, $onFailure);
        $match=$api->getMatch($games->match_id);
    }
    $api->commitAsync();
    echo $t."<br>";

?>
```

Let me know how this goes for you. I wasn't paying attention before to notice you're also looping through multiple matches (onSuccess called multiple times).

Comment: im getting the exactly same result as before , i dont know why

Comment: but what i've notice is , it seems the foreach with $custom is passing through  the $onsucess function , if i erase everything on  the $onsuccess function , and echo just "test" , it prints out  33 "test" , the exact same number of matchesid that i have on my db

Comment: I actually misread your code before, my apologies. updated answer coming soon.

Comment: shortly ~= 5 hours I guess. but see update if still needed